# Como implementar Google Maps en una Web

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-v3

Me gustaría implementar Google Maps en mi página web pero no sé cómo hacerlo exactamente. En el perfil de los usuarios tengo un apartado donde indican su dirección (Provincia, calle, CP, etc) Me gustaría poder mostrar la ubicación de los usuarios (cuando estos lo permitan). Había pensado en hacer algo tal que así:
Las URI de google maps se compone de `https://www.google.es/maps/place/` digamos que es la base e indica el lugar añadiendo cada palabra separada por un `+` por ejemplo: `https://www.google.es/maps/place/rambla+de+catalunya+110` entonces coger toda la información del usuario y separar cada palabra y unirlo todo en una URI para que se pueda acceder directamente a esa dirección.

Se que parece un poco cutre pero es lo primero que se me ha ocurrido. Si alguien sabe alguna forma de hacerlo un poco más profesional se lo agradecería. Por si fuese necesario saberlo, en mi web uso PHP, MYSQL, JS como lenguajes

Cualquier propuesta es bienvenida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu buscas un mapa *embeded*. El URI es parecido al que estabas diciendo y se utiliza un **iframe**.

```
  <iframe src="//www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Harrods,Brompton%20Rd,%20UK
      &zoom=17
      &key=YOUR_API_KEY">
  </iframe>
```

Para más información: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/